# Jquery dropdownlist with button

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I have a simple drop-down box and when its click and display values I want to add "Remove" option (see at right side) as below google image.

I research and I think this is not possible in drop down, so I implement  text box with `Jquery-Autocomplete` option that is also have issue.

Can any body have experience / idea this and how to implement via jquery?

[image]

I have done with autocompleted text box but is still getting only string value and we want to include html controls and events in this text box.

[image]

Comment: What exactly you want to know?

Comment: you can add a button in every link by yourself;

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to use a dynamically generated div for the dropdown, so that it could contain the selection and the remove link

1. detect user input
2. use ajax to send input to server and query
3. server send back query (including the choice and id for the "Remove" link)
4. show on dynamically created div